# Cases with multiple flexible array members in C?

Tags: c

**The Problem:**
I receive dynamically sized structures through the network and store it on disk. Now I would like to provide functions to work with this continuous memory block.

**Example:** The following of course doesn't work, it's just an example:

```
typedef struct person {
  size_t name_size;
  const char name[];
} person;

typedef struct group {
  size_t caption_size;
  const char caption[];
  size_t group_size;
  person people[];
} group;

person *group_get_people(const group *g);
const char *person_get_name(const person *p);
size_t person_get_name_size(const person *p);
...
```

**Requirements:** The API should have types, so it's clear what to pass and the compiler should warn if the wrong type is passed.

**What I've tried:** I was currently thinking of `typedef person void;`, and just calculate the offsets in the implementation. However, compilers wouldn't warn if the wrong type was passed.

**Question:** How could I represent such data structures? What's the most common way to do that?

Comment: The typical solution to your problem would be plain pointers and dynamic allocation. If you can't do dynamic allocation but have to use the single contiguous block you're given, then it can still be solved by having pointers pointing to specific positions inside the block of memory you have.

Comment: And I'm very curious about the *real* problem you need to solve with such a solution. *Why* can't you (presumably) use pointers and dynamic allocation? What is the requirements that made you pick such a design? Perhaps there's other possible designs to fit the requirements, or other solutions to the design, which we might be able to help you with if we only knew more details and possible use-case.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The thing is, this data is received through network and stored on disk. You could think of it to be a data structure like BSON or similar.

Comment: The compiler cannot tell you if you are wrong when you make it point to arbitrary data and basically tell it "this *is* a `person`". If you want to ensure your code does not continue when the data is not synchronized anymore, you could add a set of checks, though ("can this be a valid `name`").

Comment: @OznOg I know, but I don't know how I could represent this structure.

Comment: IMHO you should break things up by reading each part in a sequence. you receive the byte stream and then you read your caption, then read the number of persons, then each person, each time getting the input stream directly

Comment: Could you have an array of `struct group` entries?  If so, how are you going to maintain your flat-memory image if the name of a caption or person grows, or a new person is added to a group?  I suppose that the thinking is "I want to keep the memory flat so I can simply write it over the network on demand", but I think that is likely to be misguided.  The structures you use can use pointers to the arrays instead of FAM.  Serialization will be needed to handle changes in the data anyway (or you end up doing block moves on most changes).  A lot depends on what you'll do with these types.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for the tip. In my case it's really mostly about receiving, then reading and finally storing it.

Comment: So, the data is all 'read-only'; the code won't modify the contents of a group once it is received.  Will you ever need multiple groups all in a single contiguous block of memory, or will you only be dealing with separate groups each in their own separate contiguous block of memory?  My impression is that your data structures shouldn't attempt to be 'flat'; you should use pointers in them.  Your group structure might contain an extra pointer and size member that points to the contiguous memory for write operations.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I am not sure whether I can follow you, but my real data structure is actually much more complex than the example provided in the question, so I suppose multiple groups could happen. I actually thought I'd like to avoid needless additional memory allocations. How would you store and send the data across the network if any of the structures contain pointers?

Comment: A lot depends on information not yet revealed — like what does the network message look like, and how does the receiver know how much data is part of the message, and so on.  You've not said whether you ever send information for a single person over the wire, or whether you only send the information for a single group over the wire  My expectation is that the data structures use to access the data once it is received are only marginally related to the data structure used to receive the data. Somewhere, there's a sending end of this process too — so I think there's a danger of a blinkered view.

Comment: However, extracting all the information I regard as relevant is going to be hard work, one comment at a time.  I am happy to leave things as they are if you are.  My view is that the accepted answer is not going to help much (but who am I to contest it if you're happy with it), but I'm not aware of all the ins and outs of what you're trying to do, and comments are not the place to find that out.  Serialization and deserialization is a searchable topic, albeit with lots of extraneous stuff showing up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot represent *conditional* memory layouts with type safety in C, but you can provide type-safe *pointer* wrappers as structs with a pointer as a single member. Something like that:

```
typedef struct group_ptr {
    void* p;
} group_ptr;

typedef struct person_ptr {
    void* p;
} person_ptr;

person_ptr group_get_person(group_ptr g, size_t i);
```

Unfortunately, I don't see an easy way to handle constness other than by adding more classes like `const_group_ptr`, `const_person_ptr`.

Comment: Thanks! This is actually quite helpful. Would it be a good idea to use incomplete struct types (forward declarations) instead of wrapping pointers?

Comment: It could work, but I don't think it's a good idea, because it confuses the readers of your code: they will try to find the definition of the type, but won't succeed.

Comment: I'd rather use opaque types.  When was the last time that you looked for the internal details of the `FILE` structure?  (Not a perfect example; it usually is available in the header, but you should not write code that depends on the internals of the structure unless you want to use platform-specific features.  On POSIX systems, a `DIR` structure would be a better example.)  People can be told "this is an opaque type" — they're then mostly wasting effort looking for the definition.  Avoid `void *`, even when wrapped.

Answer (score 1):

I would propose something like this (this is pseudo code, as you did not provide much) but it is the main idea.
Basically, you have 'classical' structures group and person that can be allocated ans linked with standard pointers (as mentioned in comments) and you have flat_person and flat_group structs for reading the serialized data.
I did little check on stream length here, careful, this would be really necessary for a working code.

```
typedef struct person {
  size_t name_size;
  const char name[];
} flat_person;

typedef struct {
  size_t caption_size;
  const char caption[];
} flat_group_caption;

typedef struct {
  size_t group_size;
  flat_person people[];
} flat_group;

group *read_group(const void *stream, size_t len) {

    const char *curr_pos_in_stream = stream;
    /* considering you have a group struct with 'traditional' linked
     * lists to hold several persons */
    group *g = malloc(sizeof(*g));
    const flat_group_caption *fgc = stream;
    /* Check if stream can hold the size of caption and then the
     * declared caption itself */
    if (len < sizeof(fgc->caption_size)
        || len < sizeof(fgc->caption_size) + fgc->caption_size)
        return NULL;

    group_add_caption(g, fgc->caption, fgc->caption_size);

    curr_pos_in_stream += sizeof(fgc->caption_size) + fgc->caption_size;
    len -= sizeof(fgc->caption_size) + fgc->caption_size;

    flat_group *fg = (void *)curr_pos_in_stream;

    curr_pos_in_stream += sizeof(fg->group_size);
    /* FIXME check len is still big enougth */
    len -= sizeof(fg->group_size);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < fg->group_size; i++) {
        const flat_person *fp = (void *)curr_pos_in_stream;

        if (len < sizeof(fp->name_size)
            || len < sizeof(fp->name_size) + fp->name_size) {
           free(g);
           return NULL;
        }

        person *p = malloc(sizeof(*p));
        person_add_name(p, fp->name, fp->name_size);
        group_add_person(g, p); // would add the person in the linked list held by group
        curr_pos_in_stream += sizeof(fp->name_size) + fp->name_size;
        /* FIXME check len is still big enougth */
        len -= sizeof(fp->name_size) + fp->name_size;
    }
    return g;
}
```

hope this helps...

Comment: Doesn't your 'flat group' structure run foul of the restriction on structures containing a FAM cannot be a part of any other structure?  C11 [§6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers ¶3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1p3): _A structure or union shall not contain a member with incomplete or function type (…), except that the last member of a structure with more than one named member may have incomplete array type; such a structure (and any union containing, possibly recursively, a member that is such a structure) shall not be a member of a structure or an element of an array._

Comment: I would say no as it doesn't appear to me to de in one of those situations, but I'm not a standard expert...

Comment: Hmmm: interesting.  It requires the `-pedantic` option to GCC for the code to be rejected: `gcc -O3 -g  -std=c11   -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes        -pedantic -c fam47.c` ——
`fam47.c:14:15: error: invalid use of structure with flexible array member [-Werror=pedantic]`
—— `flat_person people[];` where `fam47.c` contains `#include <stddef.h>` so `size_t` is available, and the 3 `typedef` statements.  Without `-pedantic`, GCC accepts the code.

Comment: but in the end, valid or not?

Comment: It depends on whether you're adhering to what the C standard says (it says "No — invalid") or what GCC says (it says "Yes — valid").  I tend to regard extensions as unhelpful to me; my code typically has to work on machines where GCC is not the standard compiler, so I'd so "No — invalid", which is why I commented originally.  I did my homework before my second comment, which is why I can now clarify with this answer — "it depends".